# Humans have an average energy budget of $100$ Watts, but the power radiated from the body is $1000$ Watts?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, thermal-radiation, biophysics, biology

On average a human consumes around $2000$ kilocalories per day. This converts to roughly $2000000$ calories / $86400$ seconds or around $100$ joules / second giving roughly $100$ watts.

But if you use human's body temperature of 310 Kelvin, the Stefan-Boltzmann law 
$$P = e \sigma A T^4$$
says the power radiated by a human with a surface area of $2 \, \text{m}^2$ and emissitivity $1$ is 1000 watts.

What's wrong here?

Comment: It is likely in your conversion to joules, you need to multiply by 4.18 in the conversion of calories to joules

Comment: This is exactly why I wear a sweater when it is cold outside.

Comment: This means that you should be able to keep warm even when naked in extremely cold temperatures by working out hard. If you do 250 Watt on a bike, you'll burn energy at a rate of about 1000 Watt.

Comment: @Triatticus. I think he did that. Multiply 2000000 by 4.18 and divide by 86400 you get 97 watts. No?

Comment: Notes: the unit kelvin has no degree associated; and it's _watt_ not Watt.

Comment: Most of the skin area is colder than 37°C, especially if not shielded by clothes. Because of the ^4 exponent, this makes a quite big difference.

Comment: @jpa Nice catch. I think it's around 30°C to 32°C.

Comment: @jpa: It doesn't make much difference at low temperatures. At 32°C, the human skin would still radiate 960W. To only radiate 100W, the skin would need to be at 173K, that is, -100°C.

Answer (score 33):

You are forgetting that you also absorb radiation from the environment. The formula you want is

$$P_\text{net} = \epsilon A\sigma\left(T_\text{skin}^4 - T_\text{env}^4\right)$$

You can find more info on Hyperphysics: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/bodrad.html

Comment: I disagree with this answer. There is no need to invoke a heat balance. The asker did not forget anything about the surroundings of the human body. His statement would hold in deep space (where $T_\text{env}\approx 3K$) as well as room temperature. The power radiated by a human is not the expression you wrote $P_{net}$, it is the one the asker wrote.

Comment: The question makes the implicit assumption that all radiated heat must be generated within the human. But if some heat is absorbed, not as much needs to be generated. A person in deep space would be insulated by the spacesuit so that the inner surface radiates some heat back, and the outer surface is much cooler and radiates less heat to space.

Comment: If you put a human in deep space without any insulation, wouldn't, they freeze to death?

Comment: @PeterShor it should would! But this doesn't change the fact that this answer circumvents the question, and doesn't address it whatsoever. The question is about the power emitted, 2 different calculations that in principle should yield the same result, don't agree. It is not about the feeling of coldness or hotness due to radiation heat transfer, unlike what this answer seems to focus on.

Comment: @coniferous_smellerULPBG-W8ZgjR: As far as I can tell, this answer is correct and addresses the question. The body only needs to "pay" for what's missing to achieve thermal equilibrium. When there's a deficit (i.e. the surrounding is colder than the human skin), the body needs to burn more food in order for the body temperature to stay constant. In a warm bath, you need to consume less energy than when laying in the snow. And naked in space, you'd need to eat 20 000 kilocalories/day.

Comment: If you use 32°C and 20°C, you get around 160W, which is the correct order of magnitude. Since we're (usually) not walking around naked, the body needs to burn less.

Comment: @coniferous_smellerULPBG-W8ZgjR So you are just talking about one part of the heat flow, not the net heat flow?

Comment: @AaronStevens No, I am not talking about any heat flow at all. The human body emits about 100 W due to food ingestion and how it's processed in our body (at first glance, regardless of the external temperature). But calculations show that a black body at 37°C would emit an order of magnitude more power. However Eric Duminil points out that the 100W of radiation actually depends on the external temperature, and should be less the hotter it is (which actually makes sense). The current answer does not say anything about that, and claims to use a formula that would not lead to the answer.

Comment: $\epsilon$ can be different for skin and environment, right?

Comment: @coniferous_smellerULPBG-W8ZgjR: Sorry, I don't get your point, or why you think this answer isn't correct. You might want to write your own answer, it might make it easier to understand your point of view and see if it's a better fit to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:

You are going wrong in assuming that the calorie intake accounts for all of the radiation of the human body. A human body really emits a power of roughly $1\ \mathrm {kW}$.

Long answer: As you've shown, any black body near room temperature with a surface of $\sim 2 \ \mathrm {m^2}$ emits in the ballpark of $1 \ \mathrm {kW}$. This means any object with that surface area and whose emissivity is near 1, emits such a power at room temperature (so even a dead body!). The extra $100\ \mathrm W$ due to calorie intake a human can make use of is usually mostly used in heating, because body temperature is usually at a higher temperature than room temperature. Nevertheless, if the room temperature is at a higher than 37°C (human body temperature), then this extra 100W due to calorie intake will be used to keep the body temperature near  37°C, for example by sweating.

In short, the extra calorie intake usually translate in emitting $\sim 1 \ \mathrm {kW}$ + $100 \ \mathrm W$. Thus we see that the calorie intake only accounts for about 10% of the total power radiated. That's what you were missing.

Comment: @user27542 I've completely edited my answer, focusing on the important point(s) only.

Comment: A dead body is warmer than surroundings for only a short time - it cannot keep emitting 1kW unless there is energy from food coming in. Eventually it has to be balanced, with energy coming in equaling energy going out.

Comment: @jpa it sure can. All it takes is a room temperature near 30°C. It's not about net power, it's about the power radiated. And it needs not to be warmer than the surroundings. You've missed point 1 of my answer.

Comment: This is obviously not what the OP had in mind with his question. He was confused about how you could emit more energy than you take in, which is impossible. The reason that even a dead body emits energy is because it also absorbs energy from the environment.

Comment: I say, let the asker decides what he thinks answers best his question. I still believe I've done a good job in answering it. Cheers and thanks for all the comments.

Comment: True @Eric Duminil. But the other answer only says no net radiation when body temp equals room temp. It doesnt help clear confusion. Ive reedited my answer for the last time. Now i think it is a good answer cleaeing the doubts of the asker.

Comment: Okay. It looks much better now.

Comment: I have to admit it is mostly thanks to you, @Eric Duminil. Took me a lot of efforts to come up with the current version of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong, is that you are using a formula applicable to an **isolated** system and applying it to a **non-isolated** system.

As it has been pointed out, a black body with the given parameters, **radiates** about 1,000 watts (as an isolated system).  However, in an environment of the same temperature, it also **absorbs** 1,000 watts. So, the net radiation, is zero!  Only when the environment is colder than the skin temperature, would the person need to use some of the 100 watts available from the food intake.