# Why is net radiation heat loss so impossibly high in this everyday case?

Tags: thermodynamics, radiation

If a hot object (temperature $T_h$) is radiating energy to cooler surroundings (temperature $T_c$) engineers express the radiation heat loss as:

$Q = \sigma \varepsilon (T_h^4 - T_c^4) A$

which is directly derived from the black body law. $A$ is the area of the hot object, $\varepsilon$ its emissivity and $\sigma$ the Stefan-Boltzmann constant.

Even though this equation seems very well established and is really just a slightly modified version of the black body radiation equation, today I tried to apply it to a few common everyday cases and the results don’t make sense. They are impossibly high. The most disturbing case is the heat loss (due to radiation) for a human in an environment at room temperature, that I will derive below.

Let’s say a man ($T_h = 37 \deg = 310 \text{ K}$) stands in a room ($T_c = 20 \deg = 293 \text{ K}$). The surface area of a grown-up person [has been estimated](https://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=39851) to be roughly $2 \text { m}^2$. The diffusivity of human skin is also not very well known but 0.9 seems reasonable. And $\sigma$ is $5.67 \times 10^{-8}$ in S.I. units.

Which gives `0.9*(5.67e-8)*2*((310^4)-(293^4))`, close to **190 W**.

That means the heat lost as radiation by an average dude during a single day is $3600 \times 24 \times 190 \approx 16 \text{ MJ}$. That’s around 4000 kcal: food intake is not even close to simply compensating this huge heat loss (not even speaking about the amount spent as mechanical energy or anything). And that’s in a 20 degrees room! Just imagine if he goes outside on a cold winter day...

What’s wrong here?

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/431522/humans-have-an-average-energy-budget-of-100-watts-but-the-power-radiated-from?rq=1

Comment: The skin temperature of a human is not 37K, except for very localized areas which are shielded from radiative heat loss anyway. Plus, you ignored the fact that most humans wear clothes.

Comment: I thought of clothes but then we can just consider ‘human + clothes’ as the system, and since clothes don’t eat food and their emissivity should be rather close to the emissivity of the skin, it does not change the equation that much?

Comment: @Zozor consider this: if clothes don't really effect how much heat energy we lose, why do we wear more clothes when its cold?

Comment: Clothes obviously hugely affect losses by convection, as for radiation losses I don’t think they play that much of a role. But let’s assume the man is naked (why not) and his skin is 308 K instead of 310 K, if that’s closer to the truth. My point is, the result still indicates he should starve to death well within a day, which is problematic.

Comment: @Zozor When wearing clothing the radiant heat loss will be a function of the outer surface temperature of the clothing which on average should be considerablly less than the surface temperature of the skin.

Comment: @Zozor Also, how do you figure a person will starve to death "well within a day"? Assuming daily calorie input of 2000 kcal, thats a loss of 2000 kcal (4000-2000). Based on 3500 kcal per pound of fat, that's a loss of little over a 0.5 lb per day. You'd hardly starve to death in a day due to losing 0.5 pounds of fat!

Comment: It's worth noting the following: the surface of your clothes (or your skin) is radiating, therefore losing heat, which lowers its temperature. This is offset by the transfer of heat from the inside of your body, via conduction. The temperature of your clothes' surface is determined by the balance between these processes: it will converge to the temperature at which its radiation loss equals the rate at which your body heats it up. If your clothes are good insulators this rate will be slow, so the outside of your clothes will cool down until they are emitting radiation at the same slow rate.

Comment: Random fact tht might influence how you think about this: civil engineers use a figure around 140 W per person as the occupation heat load in an office environment.

Comment: you wrote "The diffusivity of human skin is also not very well known but 0.9 seems reasonable." Why "0.9" is more reasonable than, say, "0.1"?

Comment: @Zozor I have deleted my answer since dmckee and JMac, both of whom I respect based on their contributions I have seen on this site, felt that my answer distracted from the physics of your question. JMac is correct that the skin surface temperature is actually several degrees less than the core body temperature, making the losses significantly less than your calculation.

Comment: I was only addressing the fact that even if your calculations were incorrect, you should not conclude the reason why they were incorrect was because the person would starve in a day (your original thought, though you later acknowledged the person would starve in the long term). In conclusion, I support the answer by JMac.

Comment: @dmckee see my last follow up comment

Answer (score 4):

If you were a *naked* person, and your skin temperature was identical to your body temperature, that would probably make some sense (though best case scenario I would only expect ~75% of what you calculated, due to radiation surface area).  I'm pretty sure if I was naked in a room that was only 20°C, I would *personally* start to feel pretty cold.

That said, those two assumptions don't really hold.  A quick google search suggests human skin is closer to 33°, so that's already 4 degrees cooler.  Some quick math suggests this already reduces the heat transfer by ~25%.

Then you have to consider that your clothes will be *warmer* than 20°C, so the radiation heat transfer between your body and clothes is actually even lower than the temperature difference between your body and the surrounding room.

I found [this paper](http://www.fibtex.lodz.pl/pliki/Fibtex_(ert6akuc1tje52dn).pdf) which gives an equation for calculating the radiation heat transfer from the body (along with other modes of heat transfer).  It also mentions that the effective area for body radiation is usually ~75% of the total body surface area.  That would be another factor that would reduce the number.

If you want to really dig through some calculations yourself, the linked paper seems to do a really good job organizing all the different modes of heat transfer, and taking into account details like how clothing affects the overall heat transfer.

Comment: See my follow up comment to the OP.  Re your answer,

Answer (score 0):

Radiation is kept back by clothing which both has an insulation because of low thermal conductitity (air kept still) and a lower emissivity. The radiation loss you calculated is true only for a naked body without hair and fur, such a body would indeed get cold at night without radiation from the sun. At daylight, radiation from Sun and clouds (which scatter sun´s radiation) would ease out the problem.